# Moving polyline to another location in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, line, coordinates

In desktop ArcGIS 10.3, I have this polyline with xy center coordinate of it is:

[image]

18157037.6 / 65108911.9

When I zoom out (1:5000000) the map, in order to grab the polyline into the right location,  I can't see the right located layers and the problematic polyline.

I understand the polyline has a different coordinate system- but when i see the the properties of the layer- it has no coordinate system:

[image]

and I try to move this polyline (center of it) into 181586/651079 (the right coordinate system).

I tried to use the tool "Move" in the editor- but the polyline just located somewhere in the space - but not in the wanted xy coordinate.

Also, I tried to convert the coordinate system of the polyline into Israel TM grid- but with no success.

Comment: I don't think you want to "move" this data. If you had the correct coordinate reference, it would move itself. Which makes this a duplicate of our most common question. Please [edit] the question to specify the exact coordinate systems associated with your layers, and explain why you need to change the position of geodata on such a massive scale.

Comment: If you want to move it you can do it using da.UpdateCursor

Comment: Try 2 screeens and spatial adjustment toolbox.

Comment: It sounds like two issues. You've got CAD data in...centimeters? and there's also a different datum/geographic coordinate reference system (GeoCRS). Maybe figure out what it's in, modify the projCRS to use the custom centimeters units, reproject the data to the projCRS you want to use.